# What's the difference between "tomorrow's meeting" and "meeting tomorrow"

Tags: differences

What's the difference between "tomorrow's meeting" and "meeting tomorrow"?

Regarding these sentences below, are both correct?

> I have to attend the tomorrow's meeting.
>   I have to attend the meeting tomorrow.

Comment: If you drop "the" from the first version, they mean pretty much exactly the same.

Answer (score 8):

The first sentence is not correct. It should be "I have to attend tomorrow's meeting". "The" is normally used to indicate a specific item, for example, "the meeting" refers to a particular meeting, while "a meeting" is just any meeting. Since the meeting is already singled out by it being "tomorrow's" meeting, using "the" is incorrect.

Additionally, the second sentence can have two slightly different meanings. The speaker could be referring to the meeting which is tomorrow, or the time they are attending the meeting(tomorrow). This could be relevant if the meeting continued for more than one day.

Comment: I think this is right but I believe it would be worth writing it out in more detail.

Comment: I'm not an expert - perhaps you could help?

Comment: Well, all your facts are right. Maybe I'll just post an answer to say what I mean.

Comment: thanks, the technical definitions were what I was missing.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with typell. I'll just add a little.

> I have to attend tomorrow's meeting.

Here the word *tomorrow's* describes the meeting. It is **adjectival**.

> I have to attend the meeting tomorrow.

Here tomorrow is an **adverb** that qualifies *attend*.